# Is there an alternative way decorate year of death?

Tags: symbols

I have written short biographies of various scientists from all backgrounds. I have used the format

Stephen Hawking (* 1942 † 2018)

to denote year of birth and death. Since the cross is a Christian symbol, and many of the scientists I'm covering are from non-Christian or irreligious backgrounds, I wonder if there is a more appropriate symbol to be used.

Comment: b.1942 d.2018 ?

Comment: Is the star a pagan symbol? A Moslem one? Would that offend adherents of some religions? One has to be careful not to be so precious about observing proprieties that one finds it impossible to say anything at all. _Of course, it's best to try to avoid offence if possible – but within reason. And yes, this sometimes involves difficult decisions._

Comment: Are there, or are there not, widely accepted - perhaps even, international - standards for that notation?

If there are, why not follow them?

If not, why not propose your ideas in whatever groups you belong to?

Either way, how did "decorate" come into this? Did you not mean "designate"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are dealing with scientists, then you will know that scientists value accuracy above sensitivities.

But more than that you should note that ***it is not a "Christian cross"*** at all: it is a printers' mark known as a "dagger": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)

> A dagger, obelisk, or obelus (†) is a typographical symbol that usually indicates a footnote if an asterisk has already been used. The term "obelisk" derives from the Greek: ὀβελίσκος (obeliskos), which means "little obelus"; from ὀβελός (obelos) meaning "roasting spit".
>
> It was originally represented by the subtraction ( − ) and division ( ÷ ) symbols by Ancient Greek scholars as critical marks in manuscripts.
>
> A double dagger or **diesis** (‡) is a variant with two handles that usually marks a third footnote after the asterisk and dagger.
>
> The triple dagger (⹋) is a variant with three handles and is used by medievalists to indicate another level of notation.

The other point is that in your example, neither the asterisk nor the dagger are required: The lifespan of a person is usually given as "**Name (1937 - 2015)**"

Addendum: Stephen Hawking was not a Christian.